# async function doesn't wait await fetch

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I have a function that must validate some artist from Spotify API but, when I run it, `artists[]` remains empty because the function is not waiting on the fetch: it fills the variable user without having set artists.

```
let artists = []

function setArtists(input) {
  artists.length = 0
  let parsedInput = input.value.split(",")
  parsedInput.forEach(artist => {
    validateArtist(artist)
  })
}

async function validateArtist(s) {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("Token")
  let url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=" + s
  console.log(url)
  await fetch(url, {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        refreshToken(s)
      }
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(searchedResults => searchedResults.artists.items.length != 0)
    .then(isArtist => {
      if (isArtist) {
        artists.push(s)
      }
    })
}
```

Here is where I call the function; I call it before so it can fill the `artists` variable:

```
setArtists(document.getElementById("artistiPreferiti"))
    var user = {
            username: document.getElementById("username").value,
            email: document.getElementById("email").value,
            password: document.getElementById("password").value,
            gustiMusicali: document.getElementById("gustiMusicali").value,
            artistiPreferiti: artists
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: forEach with async await never works like you expect. Use a regular for loop

Comment: Your `setArtist()` function will need to be `async` also, and it will need to `await` the validation function call. Something else will have to `await` the call to `setArtist()`, because only after the promise is satisfied will the array be updated as you expect.

Comment: @JaromandaX is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the pieces one at a time, `setArtists` must indeed by async and should probably run the validation currently (since the validations are not interdependent).

There's no need for the `artists` global in the containing scope. In  fact, having it will encourage errors.

```
// clarifying... input is a comma-delimited string describing artists
// validate each one with spotify, and return an array of the valid artists
async function setArtists(input) {
  let parsedInput = input.value.split(",")
  let promises = parsedInput.map(validateArtist);
  let results = await Promise.all(promises);  // validate all of them at once
  // return just the valid inputs, not the nulls
  return results.filter(r => r);
}
```

The `validateArtist` method mixes async styles. Here it is with uniform style and with a clearer objective:  to just validate and return an artist...

```
// given the params of an artist, lookup on spotify and return a
// a promise that resolves to the input artist if valid, null otherwise
async function validateArtist(s) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("Token")
  const url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=" + s
  console.log(url)
  const response = await fetch(url, {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
      }
  });
  if (response.status === 401) {
    refreshToken(s)
  }
  const searchedResults = await response.json();
  const isArtist = searchedResults.artists.items.length != 0;
  // notice, no side-effects here, resolve to the input artist or null
  return isArtist ? s : null;
}
```

Lastly, your caller must be async also, and await the `setArtists` result...

```
async function theCaller() {
  // notice - no need for a global. now it's a local here...
  let artists = await setArtists(document.getElementById("artistiPreferiti"))
  var user = {
    username: document.getElementById("username").value,
    email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    password: document.getElementById("password").value,
    gustiMusicali: document.getElementById("gustiMusicali").value,
    artistiPreferiti: artists
  } 
  // ...
```

As a side note, there might be valuable stuff in the artist array that spotify returns, some super set of the data you queried with.  If you'd rather keep the results around, you can make up a policy to pick the first matching artist returned in the array of spotify matches...

```
// updating the functional comment:
// given the params of an artist, lookup on spotify and return a
// a promise that resolves to the first found artist or null if no matches are found

  .then(searchedResults => {
    let items = searchedResults.artists.items;
    return items.length ? items[0] : null;
  });
```

Comment: don't work, it still does not await the fetch

Comment: Just noticed that that method calling spotify incorrectly mixed await and then, most probably leaving you the impression that the fetch wasn't awaited.  I'm certain it will await now. Also added error handling in case something else is going wrong in there.

Comment: thanks man now it works!!! But why with then it wasn't working?

Comment: Glad it helps. I think it was awaited, but the result was not returned.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Promise.all() like:

```
const artists = ['first', 'second'];

const promises = artists.map(artist => fetch(url+artist));

Promise.all(promises)
.then(response => {
  // handle response
})
.catch(err);
```

or

```
const returnedData = await Promise.all(promises).catch(err);
```